# escaping quotes from bash script in an ssh command for a stringstream

Tags: c++, string, bash, stringstream

I have a bash script that I'd like to execute remotely using ssh.

Here's the script:

```
(
vmnames="$(/usr/bin/VBoxManage list vms | grep -o -w -P -e '\"([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\"' | sed s/\"//g)"
for vm in $vmnames
do
    ip="$(/usr/bin/VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate ${vm} | grep 'V4/IP' | grep -o -w -P -e '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' | sed s/\"//g)"
    echo "${vm} ${ip}"
done
)
```

As I'd like to execute this remotely using ssh, I need to quote the whole script:

```
stringstream ssCmd;
    ssCmd   << "sshpass -p '" << sPass << "' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "
            << sUser << "@" << sHost << " "
            << "\""
            << my_script_should_go_here
            << "\"";
```

I can't seem to figure out how to correctly quote the script so that its correctly interpreted.

Is there an automated tool I could use to escape the script correctly, or can someone suggest how properly escape the script?

nb - for the curious - the script requires guest additions to be installed on each of the VMs in order that it'll return IP address information for each VM.

**update**

I finally ended up going with the following:

```
// base64 encode the script for decode on remote system

static const std::string k_sGetHostIpScript = "KAp2bW5hbWVzPSIkKC91c3IvYmluL1ZCb3hNYW5hZ2UgbGlzdCB2bXMgfCBncmVwIC1vIC13IC1QIC1lICdcIihbYS16QS1aMC05X10rKVwiJyB8IHNlZCBzL1wiLy9nKSIKZm9yIHZtIGluICR2bW5hbWVzCmRvCmlwPSIkKC91c3IvYmluL1ZCb3hNYW5hZ2UgZ3Vlc3Rwcm9wZXJ0eSBlbnVtZXJhdGUgJHt2bX0gfCBncmVwICdWNC9JUCcgfCBncmVwIC1vIC13IC1QIC1lICdcZHsxLDN9XC5cZHsxLDN9XC5cZHsxLDN9XC5cZHsxLDN9JyB8IHNlZCBzL1wiLy9nKSIKZWNobyAiJHt2bX0gJHtpcH0iCmRvbmUKKQ==";

    stringstream ssCmd;
    ssCmd   << "sshpass -p '" << sPass << "' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "
            << sUser << "@" << sHost << " "
            << "\"eval 'echo " << k_sGetHostIpScript << " | base64 --decode | bash'\"";
```

Comment: There are lots of automation tools for stuff like this. e.g. Puppet, Chef, Ansible. Also, if this is Virtual Box driven, you could use Vagrant.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have a lot of virtual machines, you are better off using a customised tools to execute commands remotely and attain the information. There's a lot more information on the web.

Comment: i need a tool to automate the escaping of the script, not to execute the script.

Comment: Do you have to pass the script along like this (thus needing to escape it) ? If you need to execute it remotely you could do it more easily in 2 steps. First copy the script over via scp and then execute it. Optionally delete it once you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have escaped strings in your bash script, so you have to escape the escaped strings.

For example let's assume you have the following line in a bash script:

```
foo=$(printf "1st line\n2nd line\n3rd line\n" | grep -a "[0-2].*")
```

To append the code snippet above to e.g. an `std::stringstream`, you have to escape all escape characters (`\`) and all quotation marks as follows:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "foo=$(printf \"1st line\\n2nd line\\n3rd line\\n\" | grep -a \"[0-2].*\")"
```

To make your life easier, you can use e.g. [this tool](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/cpp_text_escape.php?lang=en) to convert your script to C++ escaped string.

Comment: dude, thanks for that reference, that tool is awesome.  Definite candidate for sublime text plugin

Comment: @stackuser, in Sublime Text 3, you can use the [Stringify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Stringify) plugin to achieve the same. That plugin is a bit inconvenient for first sight (uses Command Palette) but useful.